# Making non focusable elements focusable for jump links, but don't use tabindex="0"

Tags: javascript, accessibility, tabindex

Sometimes it's needed to make non focusable elements focusable to screenreaders.

An example: when creating jump links like `<a href="#target">Skip to content</a>` that jump to an ID, it's important that the specific element also gets the focus, so not only the viewport is scrolled to the element, but also the focus is set there. Otherwise, a keyboard only user will "jump" back to the beginning of the document as soon as he tries to tab to the next element (expecting the tabbing would begin from the `#target` object).

Here `tabindex="0"` is needed, which works as expected. The not so nice thing is that, in other use cases (e.g. when tabbing through the whole page), this is annoying (you usually don't want to focus non focusable elements).

Sort of a workaround could be: create a javascript which, on page load...

- scans the entire document for links that are targeting an ID
- adds a call to a function `addVolatileTabindex` to each of those links on activation

  - when the link is activated, `addVolatileTabindex` adds a `tabindex="0"` to the targeted element, then focuses it
  - it also adds a call to `removeVolatileTabindex` when the focus is lost from the targeted element
  - when `removeVolatileTabindex` is called, the `tabindex="0"` is removed again

This way, `tabindex="0"` is only there when it's really needed, and otherwise it's not.

Is there maybe already an existing solution for this? Or are there other ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `tabindex="-1"` also, you can remove the tabindex once the user tabs off (on blur) that way the focus will never go to the element - even if a user clicks it.

Comment: Ah you're right, that's much better. But still I have to set the focus using JavaScript, right?

Comment: That's what webaim.org does.  The first TAB will reveal the "skip to main content" link.  When you select it, focus is moved to the appropriate area, focus() is called, and tabindex is removed.  They also have a nice yellow fadein so it's obvious where you are.  When you TAB after having gone to the main area, the tab moves to the next focusable thing in that main area, the same behavior you're trying to achieve.  I figured you might want to look at an example.

Comment: Good answer. I don't understand (or remember) in which case Javascript is necessary to set the focus when using tabindex="-1". Is there any bug in some browser? I can't reproduce it.

Comment: @adam, it might be easier if you posted a separate question regarding tabindex since this comment area has limited characters for a response and is technically for just commenting on the posted answer and not for answering other questions.  That being said, it sounds like you might not be familiar with tabindex.  That property allows an element to receive focus.  It doesn't actually move the focus to the element.  If you set tabindex to 0, then you'll be able to get to the element using the TAB key.  If you set it to -1, then you must use javascript to put the focus on the element.

Comment: (continued)  You can try a simple example.  Make a <div> and a <button>.  When you click on the button, have it send focus to the <div>.  It won't work because a <div> doesn't natively accept focus.  But if you change it to <div tabindex='-1'>, then it will work.  The -1 just allows the element to receive focus.  You can try it again with tabindex='0' and now you can use the TAB key to get to the <div>.  (side note: you may not notice if the <div> gets focus if you don't have a focus indicator.  Add <style>div:focus {outline:#00FF00 solid 4px}</style> to make the focus indicator more obvious).

Comment: @slugolicious: My question was precisely asking the poster for precisions **about the necessity to use javascript to set the focus when an element already has the tabindex=-1** attribute (see unobf own comment above your first one). I think it was due to a bug in some browser but I can't remember which one.